# Retrieve the historical close price for each stock from yahoo finance?

Tags: vb.net, yahoo-finance

I am writing the program in vb.net. My program will generate the graph of the return of the closed price for each stock. Now, I have to go to yahoo finance and select the date and download. Then I opened the file in excel and copy the column of the closed price. Then I paste those values in notepad. Finally, my program reads the notepad file and generates the graph.

So is there anyway I can just type the symbol in vb.net and I get all the values I need without going through all these steps?

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_graph_stock_history.html

The code below will give you what you need to retrieve the stock quotes from Yahoo. You simply have to pass the ticker symbol to GetStockPrices. I believe, by default, it downloads a year of historical data from google finance.

Really, all you need to do is google: 'vb.net download stock quote history' - and you'll find tons of stuff out there.

```
' Get the prices for this symbol.
Private Function GetStockPrices(ByVal symbol As String) As _
    List(Of Single)
    ' Compose the URL.
    Dim url As String = _
        "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?output=csv&q=" _
        & symbol

    ' Get the result.
    ' Get the web response.
    Dim result As String = GetWebResponse(url)

    ' Get the historical prices.
    Dim lines() As String = result.Split( _
        New String() {vbCr, vbLf}, _
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim prices As New List(Of Single)()

    ' Process the lines, skipping the header.
    For i As Integer = 1 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim line As String = lines(i)
        prices.Add(Single.Parse(line.Split(","c)(4)))
    Next i

    Return prices
End Function
```

Comment: Trust me, I tried google but all of them gave me like crazy code or something to do with SQL. I'm really just a beginner. Also, the code doesn't work. Thanks anyway